# I found number of blocks using following script, how can i kill all the schema related to this object blocks?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I found number of blocks using following script, how can i kill all the schema related to this object blocks? how can i get sid and serial# to kill for that owner

```
    SELECT o.object_name, COUNT(*) number_of_blocks
  FROM DBA_OBJECTS o, V$BH bh
 WHERE o.data_object_id = bh.OBJD
   AND o.owner != 'SYS'
   and o.object_name  like '%JOBS_LOG%'
 GROUP BY o.object_Name
 ORDER BY COUNT(*);
```

Comment: found object_name=JOBS_LOG  and number_of_blocks=452

Comment: `sid` and `serial#` exist only for connected (currently or some time back in history) sessions. They are not related to some schema or object. Please clarify your needs.

Comment: I just try to figure out why the procedure is not compiled in my db server. whenever I tried to compile sql developer is just showing script is running and it is stuck. Might be the same tables are blocked which was used in that procedure might the issue.

Comment: How can I figure out the reason behind not being compiled procedure.

Comment: Tables being used would not block PL/SQL compilation. It might block the procedure *execution*.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86579/how-to-find-out-who-is-active-and-locking-the-oracle-database

Comment: v$locked_object won't show procedures in use, for that you must use v$access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `v$bh` for this purpose. That has the buffers currently in the buffer cache, which could have been loaded many hours or days ago and has no relation to current usage or locking of any kind. For compiling PL/SQL procedures and functions and packages, you need to ensure that nobody is executing them. To find out who is executing, you can use `v$access` (or `gv$access` in RAC). Here's a sample kill script:

```
BEGIN
  FOR rec_owner IN (SELECT s.sid,s.serial#,s.inst_id
                      FROM gv$access a,
                           gv$session s
                     WHERE a.object = 'MYPROC'
                       AND a.type = 'PROCEDURE' -- or PACKAGE or FUNCTIION etc..
                       AND a.sid = s.sid
                       AND a.inst_id = s.inst_id
                       AND s.username != 'SYS'
                       AND s.type = 'USER')
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '''||rec_owner.sid||','||rec_owner.serial#||',@'||rec_owner.inst_id||''''; -- if non-RAC, leave out the ,@ and inst_id.
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: I tried with this script and kill the sessions, but when I try to call procedure again there is session related to that procedure and the database stuck(hang).

Comment: I suggest engaging your DBA, this is not normally a development task.